# Splitting pandas data frame based on column name

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to split a pandas data frame based on the column name? As an example consider the data frame has the following columns `df = ['A_x', 'B_x', 'C_x', 'A_y', 'B_y', 'C_y']` and I want to create two data frames `X = ['A_x', 'B_x', 'C_x']`and `Y = ['A_y', 'B_y', 'C_y']`.

I know there is a possibility to do this:

```
d = {'A': df.A_x, 'B': df.B_x, 'C': df.B_x}
X = pd.DataFrame (data=d)
```

but this would not be ideal as in my case I have 2200 columns in `df`. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Is the number of splits (eg the x and y in your case) limited?

Comment: @joris yes. In my case I have equal x and y columns and I require to split in two partitions (one with the x and the other with y)

Comment: you don't need to, just simple masking will do: ie. `x = df[['A_x', 'B_x', 'C_x']]`

Comment: @Anzel Thanks for your explanation and solution. As tempting as it sounds to me, I guess simple masking of 1100 columns could be an overkill for me :)

Comment: lol.. my apologies I didn't notice you have "2200" columns, I jumped too quick to a conclusion. but hey same rules apply you can do: `df[[col for col in df.columns if col.endswith("_x")]]`. But hey just follow unutbu's solution, he's GOD of pandas

Comment: @Anzel thanks for the alternative. I would stick to unutbu's solution, as suggested ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use [`df.filter(regex=...)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 10),
                  columns='Time A_x A_y A_z B_x B_y B_z C_x C_y C-Z'.split())
X = df.filter(regex='_x')
Y = df.filter(regex='_y')
```

yields

```
In [15]: X
Out[15]: 
        A_x       B_x       C_x
0 -0.706589  1.031368 -0.950931
1  0.727826  0.879408 -0.049865

In [16]: Y
Out[16]: 
        A_y       B_y       C_y
0 -0.663647  0.635540 -0.532605
1  0.326718  0.189333 -0.803648
```